# loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable log method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logarithm

For an assignment I have to calculate the log returns of stocks.
After I write `df_ret = 100*(np.log(df) - np.log(df.shift(1)))` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'log'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-aa65effd67b2> in <module>()
----> 1 df_ret = 100*(np.log(df) - np.log(df.shift(1)))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type str which has no callable log method
[enter image description here][1]
```

Is someone able to help?

Comment: What is in the dataframe?

Comment: df=pd.read_csv('tickerdata.csv')

the csv file consists of different stocks and their closing prices between 2010-2020

Comment: `df` contains `str` elements, which can't be using an a numeric `np.log` function.  YOu do understand what `log` does, don't you?  Do you know what your `df` contains?

Comment: The columns are the different names of tickers/stocks and the rows represent dates from 2010 till 2020 (monthly data). The data therefore consists of closing prices for different stocks every month